# Как запустить код в стеке?

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Требуется запустить код в стеке. Имеется процедура fun.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap : none

includelib D:/masm32/lib/user32.lib

include D:/masm32/include/user32.inc

.data
text1 db "Text1",0
text2 db "Text2",0

.code
fun proc
    push 0
    push offset text1
    push offset text2
    push 0
    call MessageBoxA
    ret
fun endp

start:
    call fun
    ret
end start
```

На просторах интернета столкнулся с интересной возможностью запускать код из стека, но не нашел достаточной информации для того чтобы провернуть этот трюк самостоятельно. Не могли бы вы подсказать как это реализовать.

Comment: Записать все байты функции в стек, потом запустить, перед этим удостоверившись что в ОС отключен DEP (защита от исполнения данных).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мучался я долго, и пришел вот к такому решению этой задачи.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap : none

includelib D:/masm32/lib/user32.lib
includelib D:/masm32/lib/kernel32.lib

include D:/masm32/include/user32.inc
include D:/masm32/include/kernel32.inc

.data

text1 db "Hello from stek",0
text2 db "Hi",0


.code

fun:                          ;функция записываемая в стек
    push eax
    push 0
    push offset text1
    push offset text2
    push 0   
    lea  eax, MessageBoxA
    call eax
    pop eax
    nop
    nop                  
    nop                        ; nop'ы нужены для того чтобы размер записываемой функции был кратен dword
    ret                        ; тк мы записываем порциями по 4 бита 
fun_end:

start:

    pusha
                                ; функцию записываем с конца
    mov eax, offset fun_end     ; получаем конец функции

    push_code:                  ; цикл записи в стек

    cmp  eax,   offset fun      ; сравниваем c началом функции  
    je   end_push_code          ; если весь код записан выходим  

    mov  edx,   dword ptr [eax-4] ; считываем dword кода 

    push edx                    

    sub  eax,   04h             ; вычитаем 4 бита - ранее считанный dword
    jmp  push_code              ; продолжаем записывать код

    end_push_code:


    call esp                    ; вызываем фунуцию изстека

    mov  eax,   offset fun_end  ; пользуясь той же логикой вынимаем из стека все что записали

    pop_code:
    cmp  eax,   offset fun
    je   end_pop_code
    pop  edx
    sub  eax,   04h         
    jmp pop_code
    end_pop_code:

    popa

    push 0
    call ExitProcess

end start
```

Прошу извинить за овно код, но это работает.